# mathematical function which rounds down k to n unless k > n+1, where n is integer

Tags: functions

So the floor function would round down k to n if k >= n+1, is there a commonly used name/symbol for a function where it rounds down is k > n+1? So for example,

f(4)=3

f(4.0001)=4

Comment: This is one less than the ceiling function.  Thus $f(x)=\lceil x \rceil -1$

Comment: Oh of course thank you

Comment: How do I mark it as solved?

Comment: I'll post it below, then you can just accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the comments:

This is one less than the ceiling function.  Thus $f(x)=\lceil x \rceil -1$.